# Change value of dynamically created progressbar

Tags: c#

I created dynamically a bunch of textboxes, labels, and progressbar in a `TableLayoutPanel`
These I want to control from a `Parallel.Foreach` threads.
I know the name of each control so I can access them like so:

```
Table1.Invoke(
      new MethodInvoker(delegate() { 
                Table1.Controls[<name>].Text = "text to write"; 
      }));
```

But when I try to change the value of a progressbar or I try to change the style(blocks->marquee) it doesn't know the .Value of .Style option.

```
Table1.Invoke(
      new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
           Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>].Value = <percentage>; 
      }));

Table1.Invoke(
      new MethodInvoker(delegate() { 
         Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>].Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee; 
      }));
```

It gives an error that .Value and .Style cannot exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

You might want cast `Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>]` to a `ProgressBar` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast control to use ProgressBar properties.

Try this:

```
Table1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
{
    ((ProgressBar)Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>]).Value = <percentage>;
    ((ProgressBar)Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>]).Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
}));
```

Happy to help you!

Answer (score 0):

When you refer `Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>]`, this is interpreted as a `Control`, instead of as a `ProgressBar`, which [happens to be a subclass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) of `Control`.

A simple fix:

```
var progBar = Table1.Controls[<progressbar_name>] as ProgressBar;
if(progBar != null)
{
    progBar.Value =  = <percentage>; 
}
```

The if-structure should not be necessary, strictly speaking, but might in some cases avoid exceptions by skipping the attempt to set the value instead (e.g. in case the controls in your Table were not loaded or instantiated correctly).